# How to stop keyboard input on Windows 10?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, water-damage

Today, I spilled water on my keyboard. When I wipe up the water, I have to smash all the keys and by typing the keys it messes with the stuff I am doing on my computer. Is there a way to make it so that the keyboard doesn't input the key press instructions to the computer so that nothing happens while I clean my keyboard? By the way, it is a laptop, so I can't just remove the keyboard.

Comment: if there's water on the computer, the first thing you should do is power off the computer and remove the battery to prevent damage

Comment: You can hibernate it by clicking start then typing `shutdown /h`.

Comment: Get it serviced and replace the keyboard.

Comment: @John it was like only a bit, it covered like 3 keys

Comment: @essjae It was like only a bit, it covered like 3 keys

Comment: There is no such thing as “a little bit of water” to a PCB

Comment: @Ramhound Oh dear, but my computer is working fine, and it has been several hours

Comment: It might work today then fail tomorrow. You are just doing all the wrong things. Power down, remove the battery, get it serviced now. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/85275